# Angular 2 select option (dropdown) - how to get the value on change so it can be used in a function?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am trying to build a drop down with a few values.

However, on selecting a value, I want to make an API call that takes an id.

In my component.ts, I have an array of values:

```
values = [
  { id: 3432, name: "Recent" },
  { id: 3442, name: "Most Popular" },
  { id: 3352, name: "Rating" }
];
```

In my template, I am using that array as follows:

```
<select>
  <option *ngFor="let v of values" [value]="v">  
    {{v.name}}
  </option>
</select>
```

However, on picking a value from the drop down, how can I access the `id` property?  I want to use that in my function `getPhotosByType(id)`.

Thanks

Comment: I achieve your desired result by  calling `[attr.value]="v"` instead of `[value]="v"`

Answer (score 65):

My answer is little late but simple; but may help someone in future;
I did experiment with angular versions such as 4.4.3, 5.1+, 6.x, 7.x, 8.x, 9.x, 10.x, 11.x, 12.x, 13.x, 14.x using **$event** (latest at the moment)

Template:

```
<select (change)="onChange($event)">
    <option *ngFor="let v of values" [value]="v.id">{{v.name}}</option>
</select>
```

TS

```
export class MyComponent {
  public onChange(event): void {  // event will give you full breif of action
    const newVal = event.target.value;
    console.log(newVal);
  }
}
```

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: change works whenever the value of select is changed, what if we want to track whenever any value is selected, even if it is the current value? @mumair

Comment: @MayankSingh above snippet will work great when ever value is changed by user. If I get you correctly you want to set default value OR you want to compare the selected value is equal to current (predefined) value. can you please further explain?

Comment: I need to add columns to table on select of any value from the dropdown, but a column can be added more than once, by this case I can add columns alternatively but not consecutively. So when i select a dropdown item 2 times is a row, on change will not occur @mumair

Comment: I wish I could edit the closing tag  <select> => </select>

Answer (score 28):

You need to use an Angular form directive on the `select`. You can do that with `ngModel`. For example

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h2>Select demo</h2>
    <select [(ngModel)]="selectedCity" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" >
      <option *ngFor="let c of cities" [ngValue]="c"> {{c.name}} </option>
    </select>
  `
})
class App {
  cities = [{'name': 'SF'}, {'name': 'NYC'}, {'name': 'Buffalo'}];
  selectedCity = this.cities[1];

  onChange(city) {
    alert(city.name);
  }
}
```

The `(ngModelChange)` event listener emits events when the selected value changes. This is where you can hookup your callback.

Note you will need to make sure you have imported the `FormsModule` into the application.

Here is a [**Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/0KrhA94WgKgY9pp4T35O?p=preview)

Comment: if your selectedCity is undefined in the initial state, you define a disabled option that show "select a city" by simply doing: `<option [ngValue]="undefined" disabled> Select a city </option>`

Answer (score 4):

```
values_of_objArray = [
  { id: 3432, name: "Recent" },
  { id: 3442, name: "Most Popular" },
  { id: 3352, name: "Rating" }
];

private ValueId : number = 0 // this will be used for multi access like 
                             // update, deleting the obj with id.
private selectedObj : any;

private selectedValueObj(id: any) {
  this.ValueId = (id.srcElement || id.target).value;
  for (let i = 0; i < this.values_of_objArray.length; i++) {
    if (this.values_of_objArray[i].id == this.ValueId) {
      this.selectedObj = this.values_of_objArray[i];
    }
  }
}
```

Now play with `this.selectedObj` which has the selected obj from the view.

HTML:

```
<select name="values_of_obj" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="ValueId"  
        (change)="selectedValueObj($event)" required>

  <option *ngFor="let Value of values_of_objArray"
          [value]="Value.id">{{Value.name}}</option>    
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution would be,**you can get the object itself as value if you are not mentioning it's id as value**: 
*Note: [value] and [ngValue] both works here.*

```
<select (change)="your_method(values[$event.target.selectedIndex])">
  <option *ngFor="let v of values" [value]="v" >  
    {{v.name}}
  </option>
</select>
```

In ts:

```
your_method(v:any){
  //access values here as needed. 
  // v.id or v.name
}
```

*Note: If you are using reactive form and you want to catch selected value on form Submit, 
 you should use **[ngValue]** directive instead of **[value]** in above scanerio*

Example:

```
  <select (change)="your_method(values[$event.target.selectedIndex])" formControlName="form_control_name">
      <option *ngFor="let v of values" [ngValue]="v" >  
        {{v.name}}
      </option>
    </select>
```

In ts:

```
form_submit_method(){
        let v : any = this.form_group_name.value.form_control_name;  
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Template/HTML File (component.ts)

```
<select>
 <option *ngFor="let v of values" [value]="v" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">  
    {{v.name}}
  </option>
</select>
```

Typescript File (component.ts)

```
values = [
  { id: 3432, name: "Recent" },
  { id: 3442, name: "Most Popular" },
  { id: 3352, name: "Rating" }
];

onChange(cityEvent){
    console.log(cityEvent); // It will display the select city data
}
```

(ngModelChange) is the @Output of the ngModel directive. It fires when the model changes. You cannot use this event without the ngModel directive

Answer (score -1):

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedcarrera" (change)="mostrardatos()" class="form-control" name="carreras">
    <option *ngFor="let x of carreras" [ngValue]="x"> {{x.nombre}} </option>
</select>
```

In ts

```
mostrardatos(){

}
```